# Android database not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, if-statement

In the given code my all ifs are working normally but the one in which i am checking if cp1.equals(p1) is not working. Even the Toast is not showing up.So, i tried commenting the database management part and then toasts work. I am new to Android. Please help. I really cant get my mistake.

```
     public void onClick(View view) {

        EditText u = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username1);
        EditText p = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password1);
        EditText cp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cpassword);
        EditText id=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.id);
        String u1=u.getText().toString();
        String p1=p.getText().toString();
        String e=id.getText().toString();
        String cp1=cp.getText().toString();


        if ((u1.equals("")) || (p1.equals("")) || cp1.equals("")||e.equals("")) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "No field can be left empty!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }



        if(cp1.equals(p1)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"check",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
            newDB=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            newDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+tablename+" VALUES ('"+u1+"', '"+p1+"', '"+e+"' );");
            Toast.makeText(this,"SUCCESSFULLY REGISTERED!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(register1.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
             }
         if (cp1.equals(p1)==false)
        {

                       Toast.makeText(this,"Confirm PAssword and password fields should be equal",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try writing `if (!cp1.equals(p1))` instead of `if (cp1.equals(p1)==false)` and see if the toast shows up.

Comment: try cp1.equalsIgnoreCase(p1) instead of  cp1.equals(p1).

Answer (score 0):

@shivansh mishra  please check this test code it's working...cool-:

public void onClick(View view) {

```
    String u1 = "e";
    String p1 = "b";
    String e = "e";
    String cp1 = "a";    

    if ((u1.equals("")) || (p1.equals("")) || cp1.equals("") || e.equals("")) {    

        Toast.makeText(this, "No field can be left empty!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }    

    if (u1.equals(e)) {    

        Toast.makeText(this, "equal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (cp1.equals(p1) == false) {    

        Toast.makeText(this, "Confirm Password and password fields should be equal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    

    }
}
```

Comment: This one is working fine, but what is the problem with mine..?

Comment: The problem is with my database management part.@Dileep Patel

Comment: @shivansh mishra Here is not problem in database because your database call after the Toast , you can check your code in Debug mode and please accept my answer..

Answer (score 0):

Its working perfectly for me.. Just changed `this` to `MainActivity.this`..(may not be necessary in your case).. But use `if-else`..its best practice